# Bone axis alignment

Tags: bones

Would anyone know how to align a bone with an axis in blender? 
I'm trying to set up a smooth rotation so that the crown in the pic doesn't wobble when it's turning (Blue line is my Z axis).

[image]

Comment: Pose mode or edit-mode?

Comment: @ideasman42 Pose mode.